# Efficiently adding element to the top of the list

Tags: java, list, arraylist, enums, linked-list

I have an ENUM like this from which I always get what is my `localFruit` which can be either `APPLE` or `ORANGE` or `BANANA`.

```
public enum Fruits {
    // it can have more elements here
    APPLE, ORANGE, BANANA;

    // some code
}
```

So let's say if APPLE is my `localFruit`, then `ORANGE` and `BANANA` will be my `remoteFruits`. I need to shuffle my `remoteFruits` and then make sure my `localFruit` is at the top of my list followed by `remoteFruits`.

Below is my code where I am doing shuffling and adding it original `result` list: In the below code `CURRENT_FRUIT` can be either `APPLE` or `ORANGE` or `BANANA`.

```
private static List<Fruits> getFruitsInOrder() {
    EnumSet<Fruits> localFruit = EnumSet.of(CURRENT_FRUIT);
    EnumSet<Fruits> remoteFruits = EnumSet.complementOf(localFruit);

    List<Fruits> result = new ArrayList<Fruits>(remoteFruits);
    Collections.shuffle(result);

    // first element in the list will always be the local fruit
    result.addAll(0, new ArrayList<Fruits>(localFruit));
    return result;
}
```

Since this code will be called a lot of times so wanted to see whether there is anything wrong I am doing which can be bottleneck in terms of performance? Does my code is ok in terms of performance?

My main goal is to have `localFruit` at the top of the List, and then followed  by `remoteFruits` (but this I need to shuffle them before adding into my result list).

Comment: Why not `result.add(0, CURRENT_FRUIT)`?

Comment: And then what about `remoteFruits`? For shuffling of `remoteFruits`, I need to convert to a List so that I can do that easily.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

All these solutions work too hard. Java sets are pretty efficient, but simple array access is more so. Additionally, building two sets (one with a complement operation), copying to ArrayList, then making a new ArrayList with addAll is lots of useless work and memory garbage.

The enum gives you an array of its values in order. Use it! Just swap the local element to position zero, then shuffle the rest of the array. This way you're creating exactly one data structure: the ArrayList you want to return. The rest is just reordering its elements.

Of course unless you have a huge enum or are calling this function millions of times, this discussion is academic. You won't notice the performance difference.

```
import java.util.Arrays;
import java.util.Collections;
import java.util.List;

enum Fruit { APPLE, PEAR, PEACH, PLUM, BANANA }

public class Hack {

    static List<Fruit> getFruitInOrder(Fruit local) {
        List<Fruit> list = Arrays.asList(Fruit.values());
        Collections.swap(list, 0, local.ordinal());
        Collections.shuffle(list.subList(1, list.size()));
        return list;
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        for (int i = 0; i < 10; i++) {
            System.out.println(getFruitInOrder(Fruit.PLUM));
        }
    }
}
```

On my MacBook:

```
run:
[PLUM, BANANA, PEAR, APPLE, PEACH]
[PLUM, PEACH, PEAR, APPLE, BANANA]
[PLUM, PEACH, BANANA, PEAR, APPLE]
[PLUM, PEAR, BANANA, APPLE, PEACH]
[PLUM, PEAR, APPLE, BANANA, PEACH]
[PLUM, BANANA, APPLE, PEACH, PEAR]
[PLUM, APPLE, BANANA, PEACH, PEAR]
[PLUM, APPLE, PEACH, PEAR, BANANA]
[PLUM, APPLE, PEAR, PEACH, BANANA]
[PLUM, PEACH, APPLE, PEAR, BANANA]
BUILD SUCCESSFUL (total time: 0 seconds)
```

Comment: Thanks for your suggestion. Can you add little bit description like what is the difference between your example as compared  to mine and why it is better. This will help me to understand better.

Comment: @user1950349 Set operations are costlier than accessing array elements. You are building two sets, one with complement. Then you convert the complement to an array. After shuffling, you shift the elements up by one position to make room for the first. You assign it by building an array of length 1 and using addAll. This is a whole lot of useless copying. Above code makes an array in the call to values(). The rest moves the elements of that array in place. Of course if the enum is small, it makes very little difference. The main point is that sets are overkill for this problem.

Comment: @user1950349 It's an old quotation (I can't remember who said it) that it takes a day to write 300 lines of code and three more to make it 100.

Answer (score 0):

What about this? It avoids any `ArrayList` resize performance hits by sizing it correctly the first time, and it avoids the hit you take by inserting in the list. It also supports multiple `localFruit` cleanly. I think your version was already O(n), so it's not a big deal either way.

```
private static List<Fruits> getFruitsInOrder() {
    EnumSet<Fruits> localFruit = EnumSet.of(CURRENT_FRUIT);
    EnumSet<Fruits> remoteFruits = EnumSet.complementOf(localFruit);

    List<Fruits> result = new ArrayList<Fruits>(localFruit.size() + remoteFruits.size());
    result.addAll(localFruit);
    result.addAll(remoteFruit);
    Collections.shuffle(result.subList(localFruit.size(), result.size()));
    return result;
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming the set size is fairly small, like 3 or 4 values, this is probably fine. As always with optimization, it's probably better to profile your code, then optimize. Having said that, the code looks fairly reasonable, but you are making lots of copies of lists most of which can be avoided.  Here's your code with a comment indicating each time you make a copy:

```
private static List<Fruits> getFruitsInOrder() {
    EnumSet<Fruits> localFruit = EnumSet.of(CURRENT_FRUIT);
    // Creates a new set copying all the fruits from the enum
    EnumSet<Fruits> remoteFruits = EnumSet.complementOf(localFruit);

    // Copies the set above
    List<Fruits> result = new ArrayList<Fruits>(remoteFruits);
    Collections.shuffle(result);

    // Will allocate a new array, copy the remote fruits, then add
    // another copy of the local fruit
    result.addAll(0, new ArrayList<Fruits>(localFruit));
    return result;
}
```

Those copies are all *O(n)* where *n* is the number of fruits. If *n* is less than 10 or so (and maybe even less than 100 or so) this isn't so bad. There's also the cost to allocate and free all those object. Again, not terrible but also not great. Here's an alternative implementation that makes only one copy:

```
private static List<Fruits> getFruitsInOrder() {
    // Makes one copy of all the fruits, that's it.
    ArrayList<Fruits> allFruits = new ArrayList<>(Fruits.values());
    // move the current fruit to the front. Assumes that the value of the
    // fruit is its array index: if not, you'll have to maintain that 
    // explicitly in a Map<Fruits, int>
    int curFruitIdx = CURRENT_FRUIT.value();
    Fruits curFruit = allFruits.get(curFruitIdx);
    allFruits.set(curFruitIdx, allFruits.get(0));
    allFruits.set(0, curFruit);
    // Now get a **view**, not a copy, of the rest of the list and shuffle it
    List<Fruits> toShuffle = allFruits.subList(1, allFruits.size());
    Collections.suffle(toShuffle);
    return allFruits;
}
```

Even the single copy at the top of the method can be eliminated if things don't need to be thread safe: you could just stick a copy in a static somewhere and keep manipulating that. Again, if *n* is small, the above might actually be slower than what you've got.

Basically, the above is a way to avoid making copies of long lists in a situation like this. With big lists, that's helpful. With small ones, not so much.